# write output in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am having a code to fetch the data and store the output into a csv file using python.

sample output.

```
66.100:5
247.600:388
```

when this is being written in csv file
it like below.

```
6
6
.
1
0
0
:
5
2
4
7
.
6
0
0
:
3
8
8
```

I want the output as 66.100 in one column and 5 in second column

```
row 1 -66.100 5
row 2- 247.600 388
```

Please help!!

```
    with open('lat_lon.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerows(last_price[0].text + ':' + Stock[0].text)
```

Comment: It'll be tough to help without knowing what `last_price` and `Stock` are.

Answer (score 4):

```
writer.writerows(last_price[0].text + ':' + Stock[0].text)
```

Here, the `writer` is thinking that the string you've given it is the iterable that it needs to convert into rows.
So it's trying to do something like:

```
for x in last_price[0].text + ':' + Stock[0].text:
   writerow(x)
```

Now, iterating over the string gives it each character in the string - hence the output.

What you need to do:

1. Use `:` [as the delimiter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) for your CSV file.
2. Put each of the rows in a list and pass that list to `writerows`
   or use [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!!
I tried to store the variable into list but did  not work. 
I am having a loop so i will receive five row. how the variable(last_price & Stock value can be stored in list.

Comment: We'll need to know what data you're trying to save and the expected output

Comment: this is the data coming as output if  i use to print 
print (Stock[0].text + ' | ' + last_price[0].text)

I want the same data is stored in csv file with the same format. stock in one column and price in second column
Output:-
stock | Price
 (5) | 66.700
 (388) | 248.000
 (2888) | 68.600
 (338) | 3.500
 (1716) | 1.080

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on there. Can you print the variables separately.

Comment: I tried to print the one variable but still the csv file is having each element in a new row.
This is the code

Comment: input file:-stock_list is has following data
5
388
expected output csv file  should have be

stock  Price
5        222.563
388    65.23

This is selenium code
Prakash

Comment: wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
import csv
with open('stock_list.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
  file = open('stock_list.csv', 'r')
  next(file)
  for line in file.readlines():
      source = line.strip('\n')
      print (source)
      url= "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym={0}&sc_lang=en".format(source)
      wd.get(url)
      sleep (10)
      Stock = wd.find_elements_by_class_name('col_name')

Comment: ast_price = wd.find_elements_by_class_name('col_last')
      with open('lat_lon.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(last_price[0].text+ ' '+Stock[0].text)
  wd.quit()